# Multiple if statements modifying private fields

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a class `A` defined as follows in Java:

```
public class A
{
    private String fieldName;
    private String detailFieldName;
    private String externalFieldName;
    private int formatLength;
    /* additional private members */

    void setProperty( String aPropertyName, String aPropertyValue )
    {
        try
        {
            if( aPropertyName.equals( AField.FieldName.getName() ) )
            {
                fieldName = aPropertyValue;
                return;
            }
            if( aPropertyName.equals( AField.DetailFieldName.getName() ) )
            {
                detailFieldName = aPropertyValue;
                return;
            }
            if( aPropertyName.equals( AField.ExternalFieldName.getName() ) )
            {
                externalFieldName = aPropertyValue;
                return;
            }
            if( aPropertyName.equals( AField.FormatLength.getName() ) )
            {
                formatLength = Integer.parseInt( aPropertyValue );
                return;
            }
            /* more if's */
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            /* logging exceptions */
        }
    }
}
```

The further if's are analogical, i.e. they all modify one specific private member variable of the class `A`.

The `AField` is defined as follows:

```
public enum AField
{
    FieldName( "FieldName" ),
    DetailFieldName( "DetailViewFieldName" ),
    ExternalFieldName( "ExternalFieldName" ),
    FormatLength( "FormatLength" )
    /* more fields */

    private final String name;

    AField(String aName)
    {
        name = aName;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I would like to replace the multiple `if`..`return`.. statements with the more appropriate, and easier to maintain solution. I read about using the map with each `AField` value as a key and a proper command (Command design pattern) as a value. However, my problem here is that in each of the if statements I modify one of the `A`'s class private members and in order to do that I must have access to them.

What kind of a solution can you suggest? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not create getter and setter for each property like a normal java bean? Instead of one setter with many ifs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking about this too hard.  Your set property can only modify one field at a time, so an if/return structure is just overkill IMO.  An if/else if structure would be just fine.

```
    void setProperty(String aPropertyName, String aPropertyValue) {
        try {
            if (aPropertyName.equals(AField.FieldName.getName())) {
                fieldName = aPropertyValue;
            }
            else if (aPropertyName.equals(AField.DetailFieldName.getName())) {
                detailFieldName = aPropertyValue;
            }
            else if (aPropertyName.equals(AField.ExternalFieldName.getName())) {
                externalFieldName = aPropertyValue;
            }
            else if (aPropertyName.equals(AField.FormatLength.getName())) {
                formatLength = Integer.parseInt(aPropertyValue);
            }
            /* more if's */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* logging exceptions */
        }
    }
```

You could also use your enum determine what field to assign

```
    void setProperty(String aPropertyName, String aPropertyValue) {
        try {
            switch(AField.valueOf(aPropertyName)) {
                case FieldName:
                    fieldName = aPropertyValue;
                    break;
                case DetailFieldName:
                    detailFieldName = aPropertyValue;
                    break;
                case ExternalFieldName:
                    externalFieldName = aPropertyValue;
                    break;
                case FormatLength:
                    formatLength = Integer.parseInt(aPropertyValue);
                    break;
                // more cases
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError(AField.valueOf(aPropertyName).name());

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* logging exceptions */
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to go the map route, you have to setup an interface to your fields in the class.

```
public interface APropertySetter {
    public void setProperty(String propertyValue);
}

public static class A {

    private String fieldName;
    private String detailFieldName;
    private String externalFieldName;
    private int formatLength;

    private Map<String, APropertySetter> propertySetter;
    /* additional private members */

    public A() {
        propertySetter = new HashMap<>();
        propertySetter.put(AField.FieldName.getName(), (APropertySetter) (String propertyValue) -> {
            fieldName = propertyValue;
        });
        propertySetter.put(AField.DetailFieldName.getName(), (APropertySetter) (String propertyValue) -> {
            detailFieldName = propertyValue;
        });
        propertySetter.put(AField.ExternalFieldName.getName(), (APropertySetter) (String propertyValue) -> {
            externalFieldName = propertyValue;
        });
        propertySetter.put(AField.FormatLength.getName(), (APropertySetter) (String propertyValue) -> {
            formatLength = Integer.parseInt(propertyValue);
        });
    }

    void setProperty(String aPropertyName, String aPropertyValue) {
        try {
            propertySetter.get(aPropertyName).setProperty(aPropertyValue);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* logging exceptions */
        }
    }
}
```

Pick what makes more sense to you and will help you grow as a developer...  Cheers!

Comment: Thank your for a very exhaustive answer. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What about using reflection, It will make your code so short and you also don't need to use enum.:

```
void setProperty(String aPropertyName, String aPropertyValue) {
        try {
            Field field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(aPropertyName);
            field.set(this, aPropertyValue);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* logging exceptions */
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't go with this solution.. 1. because it reduces *readability* . 2. Because it will be terribly slow when compared to plain `if` blocks

Comment: Yes you are right, reflection is always slow then direct calls. But if user wants to remove overhead and if it is not possible for him to maintain getters/setters then he can pick this solution. But yes reflection should always be your last choice.